# Horizontal UIScrollView Not Fitting iPhone 5 Screen

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview, swift3

I'm using a UIScrollView to swipe horizontally between two ViewControllers. On iPhone 6 and higher the VCs fit perfectly in the screen. However, when testing on an iPhone 5, the [second VC isn't displayed entirely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6alu.png). The scrollView will not display all of "Page 2" (the right VC), but will fit the left VC perfectly.  I have the scrollView's contentSize width set to equal 2 times the screen's width (since there are two full screen VCs).

```
let screenRect = UIScreen.main.bounds

var adminFrame : CGRect = pageTwo.view.frame;
adminFrame.origin.x = adminFrame.width;
pageTwo.view.frame = adminFrame;

var BFrame : CGRect = pageOne.view.frame;
BFrame.origin.x = 2 * screenRect.width;
self.scrollView.contentOffset.x = BFrame.width

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: screenRect.width * 2, height: screenRect.height)
```

If I arbitrarily add to the contentSize width, then it does fit better, but is not a perfect fit nor does it seem like a good solution.

Comment: Where is that code located?

Comment: Good question, it's located within the base VC, which is also a subclass of UIScrollViewDelegate, in the viewDidLoad() method.

Comment: So that is likely to be a lot of your problem right there. In `viewDidLoad`, things do not have their real sizes yet. So your answer to queries like `adminFrame = pageTwo.view.frame` are likely to be wrong.

Comment: @matt That makes perfect sense, what method would you recommend to use that would work for this?

Comment: If my theory is right, you would need to "wait" until at least after `viewDidLayoutSubviews` has been called for the first time. But watch out because it can be called many times thereafter. So if you use `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, make sure you don't run the same code multiple times.

Comment: @matt Do you have any suggestions on how to ensure the code is only called once within `viewDidLayoutSubviews`? Thank you

Comment: suggestion: If you need to swipe between ViewControllers the us "UIPageViewController" It is loads better and swipe between controller is handled by default.

Comment: Yes, actually I agree with @AbdulRehmanWarraich - see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41710711/341994

Comment: For "only called once", see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37287923/341994